# Kendo DropDown default value does not seem to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using Kendo Drop down with MVC and binding it with a model of Name,value pair. Pretty standard. Now, I want it to start with a blank option IF the model does not currently have any value for that field which is **"Vendor"** in this case.

Which mean New Vendor --> **Empty** Dropdown default value. Existing vendor --> **Current Value**

I have following code to fulfill that :

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                  .Name("Vendor")
                  .DataTextField("Name")
                  .DataValueField("VendorId")
                  .Text(Model.Vendor == null ? "" : (Model.Vendor.Name))
                  .Value(Model.Vendor == null ? "" : Model.Vendor.VendorId.ToString())
                  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetAllVendors", "Vendors")))
                  )
        </td>
```

The model that I am sending over has Vendor == Null but still the default value is not Empty but instead it has one of the values that "GetAllVendors returned"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your model have a `VendorID` like `Model.VendorID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `.OptionLabel("--Please select vendor--")` to the Kendo drop-down list builder expression to show a user-friendly message for selecting a vendor from your remote list.